# Why am I getting strange triplication of video using Webcam and Tensorflow.js?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I have a keras model trained and now I want to run this on the web. I thought this might be a good way to attempt testing out Tensorflow.js. I downloaded the Tesnroflow.js "Webcam-transfer-learning" tutorial and then modified it to get what I currently have. The working keras model performs emotion classification after reducing the size of the image to 48x48. Now in the keras model, I take a snapshot of the webcam, copy it and then draw my box and label. I was trying to do the same thing in tf.js, so I setup a canvas, got a reference to it and tried drawing to the canvas after my conversion to gray scale.

I am seeing a strange behavior where it is correctly showing the gray scale image but it is displaying it 3 times across and not sure what I am doing wrong. I have included the areas I believe the problem might reside below.  Should any more info be needed, I can share more. It was my hope that someone that has already tried performing something similar may see right away what I am clearly doing wrong.  Any info would be helpful.  Thanks!

Modified webcam.js by adding function

```
preProc() {
return tf.tidy(() => {
  // Reads the image as a Tensor from the webcam <video> element.
  const webcamImage = tf.fromPixels(this.webcamElement);

  //Resize to our image and get back single channel for greyscale
  const croppedImage = this.cropImage(webcamImage, 1);

  // Expand the outer most dimension so we have a batch size of 1.
  const batchedImage = croppedImage.expandDims(0);

  // Normalize the image between -1 and 1. The image comes in between 0-255,
  // so we divide by 127 and subtract 1.
  return batchedImage.toFloat().div(tf.scalar(127)).sub(tf.scalar(1));
});
}

/**
* Crops an image tensor so we get a square image with no white space.
* @param {Tensor4D} img An input image Tensor to crop.
*/
cropImage(img, dim=3) {
  const size = Math.min(img.shape[0], img.shape[1]);
  const centerHeight = img.shape[0] / 2;
  const beginHeight = centerHeight - (size / 2);
  const centerWidth = img.shape[1] / 2;
  const beginWidth = centerWidth - (size / 2);
  return img.slice([beginHeight, beginWidth, 0], [size, size, dim]);
}
```

From ui.js I am using drawFrame

```
export function drawFrame(image, canvas) {
  const [width, height] = [300, 165];
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const imageData = new ImageData(width, height);
  const data = image.dataSync();
  for (let i = 0; i < height * width; ++i) {
    const j = i * 4;
    imageData.data[j + 0] = (data[i * 3 + 0] + 1) * 127;
    imageData.data[j + 1] = (data[i * 3 + 1] + 1) * 127;
    imageData.data[j + 2] = (data[i * 3 + 2] + 1) * 127;
    imageData.data[j + 3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
```

Finally in index.js, when the predict button is pressed the below handler executes

```
async function predict() {
while (isPredicting) {
  const predictedClass = tf.tidy(() => {
    // Capture the frame from the webcam.
    const imgmod = webcam.preProc();
    ui.drawFrame(imgmod, grayframe);


    // Returns the index with the maximum probability. This number corresponds
    // to the class the model thinks is the most probable given the input.
    //return predictions.as1D().argMax();
    return imgmod;
  });

  const classId = (await predictedClass.data())[0];
  predictedClass.dispose();

  //ui.predictClass(classId);
  await tf.nextFrame();
  }
  ui.donePredicting();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`drawframe` is drawing the image three times.
It has to do with the shape of the input image and the way `height` and `width` are used to crop the image. If the input image were of shape [298, 160], the canvas will not be rendered as there will be an error when trying to access index that are not in `data`. For instance the size of `data` is `298 * 160` whereas the last element of the loop would try to access the element `3 * 300 * 160`. Since there are no error in the code, it indicates that the size of `data` is bigger than `[298, 160]`. At any rate, there is a mismatch in data dimension. The image are drawn 3 times because of the three channels, possibly because it was not removed before.

Instead of implementing your own way of drawing the imagedata, you can consider using `tf.toPixel` method

Comment: Thanks edkeveked. I originally tried using tf.toPixel, but I was getting a message that tf had already been destroyed which I assumed was due to the logic being in a tf.tidy.  So then I looked more at the tf.js examples and saw they were using this ui class to perform the drawing, so I followed suit.  Figured I would take this approach until I better understood tensorflow.js.  Thanks for the assist...I will look more into why drawframe is doing this.

Comment: To add more detail to the above, the error message I get when using tf.toPixel instead of ui.drawframe is: "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Tensor is disposed.".  Will post answer here should I come across the solution.

Comment: It is because of tf.tidy. Consider using it to dispose of the tensors after drawing your image

Comment: Thanks again edkeveked.  This helped immensely.  I assigned the preprocessed image using tidy and then performed the call to tf.toPixel after and I now have a normal drawing to my canvas.  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped. As for the issue with your drawframe, I think it has to do with the shape of the tensor and the way you use height and width. Could you tell what is the initial shape?

Comment: Yeah...initial shape of the webcam stream was 298x160.

Comment: what is image.shape before this instruction: "const data = image.dataSync();" when you execute drawFrame() ?

Comment: The shape there is [224, 224, 1]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187067/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-xtr33me).